# Controller Authorization not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to authorize my delete action using the Controller Authorization. Instead of using DELETE, I am sending the delete directly to the controller. Student can be deleted by instructor.
I followed the approach as explained at -

[Controller Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#controller-authorization)

Below is my function -

```
public function deleteProfile(Student $student)
 {         
    //authorize the request
    $this->authorize('deleteProfile',$student);  //$student is valid Student object
    $student->delete();
 }
```

When I try to delete it gives me exception -

> HttpException in Handler.php line 104: This action is unauthorized.

I found this approach simple so, tried to implement it. Is there anything which I am missing ?

Comment: Are `user` going to delete his own(personal) record? or some `Admin/Super User ` are deleting any `User record` please explain

Comment: Instructor can delete a student.

Comment: ok, as per my knowledge, `authorize` method checks that the records which is going to edit or delete, is it created by Loggedin User, If yes go ahead, if not, then show UN-authorize error message

Comment: Yes, I am trying to delete a record which is created by the logged in user. But still the exception is thrown.

Comment: did you created any ` Gate::allows('deleteProfile', $item);`

Comment: Do I need to create Gate::allows ?

Comment: of course, you need to create this, otherwise How Laravel knows the authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this file with your xxxPolicy.php
Add the intval() in case. And it`s work.

ProjectPolicy.php :

```
    public function destroy(User $user, Project $project)
    {
        return $user->id === intval($project->user_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a gate policy where you put the logic of who can delete the request. If by that logic the current user can delete, it will be deleted else it will throw a not authorized exception like you did.

Or else you can manually give authorization on your controller method for the user

$this->authorizeForUser($user, 'deleteProfile',$student);

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization) "The Gate will automatically return  false for all abilities when there is not an authenticated user".  So before doing any authorization, please check Auth::user() if it returns a currently authenticated user."